# Indian Passport Renewal Queries

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, india, passport-renewals

My passport is valid till May 2023. I have a valid US visa on it until 2025. However I am moving to Germany with my spouse in January 2022 as a dependent or with a work permit. I will then move alone to the UK/Canada/other EU countries for my studies in late 2022. Under such circumstances, how do I apply for my Indian passport renewal while I am still in India? Is it necessary to be present in the Passport Seva Kendra in India if I am applying for a visa renewal? Is there a possibility to renew my Indian Passport while I am in Germany, without coming back to India? Please help. Thank you, in advance, for all leads any of you can provide to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply for a new passport while in Germany at your local embassy / consulate of India, information on specifics are available at the [Embassy of India website](https://indianembassyberlin.gov.in/pages?id=eyJpdiI6IkRBb2NUZFR1Q1hWZEtcL0VIeSs1bTR3PT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IkFKWmw1UTZWbTQ2R0hRTEE0cUM5YXc9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImU4MDk0ZGE3NzA5MzM0NzA1YTZhZjA2ZDllYzIxNmEwZjQ3NzA4MmVjMzlkNTg1NTNkOWI3YjlhNTk1M2ZkOGMifQ==&subid=eyJpdiI6ImFOY0FFXC92aFwvMUZsTksyaGtUT1NHdz09IiwidmFsdWUiOiJUT2tYdXphM3FsT3VaWWprVWM4Ym1nPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI0YTUzZjJhMTMwMjg1NzU3ZjVmMmUwNmU4OWJhZTM3ZGVlYmZkNzAxNjdlNzZiY2U5YWQwMmYzYjg0ODQyY2Q5In0=).

It can take up to 7 weeks for the new passport to be issued.